# Running compiled code on another machine crash (mingw-w64 32 and 64 bit toolchain ) cryptopp

Tags: crypto++, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I have one problem that I can't understand.

First I am making program that is using Crypto++ for RSA. I have separated toolchain for 32bit and 64bit mingw-w64. So I downloaded cryptopp source and build it for 2 times for 32 bit and 64bit and copied lib and include files. I used default make...

So I have compile my code and with static libraries and when I run it on machine that is compiled,32bit and 64bit works ok. But When I copy it to another machine XP 64bit or Win7 32bit it crash on runtime. On Win7 I use only 32bit and on XP I use 32 and 64.

I was searching for a while and found that it crash on this code:

```
StringSource ss1(message, true,
        new SignerFilter(rng, signer,
            new StringSink(signature)
       )
    );
```

But running only this it doesn't crash.

```
new SignerFilter(rng, signer,
                new StringSink(signature)
           )
```

Does anyone have a clue what can it be?

This is my test code

```
AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

string privKey, privKey_Base64 = 
"MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBAMm4ybhUat8MwkHwWxwEFQ/7\
0wsJIT+Y3sIUFhwF8BslsJrhkTYYbhMYM9gHi/T5Y0m75h4jXesZNgfv0SUie1/6aWe61eZG\
bCMUgWh/6+onNtQOiJV88VgxBJG45OOinlG3l7NJpZZukiEXNqlv4dj2mWLgt6cIC8Gz2QQh\
cb9zAgERAoGANWWezukrWSkGPqGBh2p+C8KozjcfY6h3M1+rf+N0Q2vb7MM9Bso7QUor101K\
scmLOSo1YlSn62iOTWUgxhCoL4WbZK2UDxrMhdtEV+i4jtkopceJF6x5XBOBYdKPjEbJxd2m\
FPMBxA8NaI4D+WdSGCrzCSmAAp/A1qHFJZErdXkCQQD7P7htvv3slqYQMJZB+BLVMnE7TNOY\
YLCxbAVRTM70pvE/sn9DwXQEJQcOTavv6hr1AU0OC70KtYxQDo5eN7ppAkEAzYlPaAQEn0Kf\
x/lNQI/0j2rUGlJMA6m9bsw3TCR0hhmRa3HIb912o1bkYi9PTvp/JnO6UlaKvkTRq1N2EJXX\
ewJBAN2wsco/HEk5oZXQhJSPmCWG3GGABf7r5zMjE8A0tpuiXGVhQx2qsalN2Qye4wDdn1Cm\
y4TdLlS+TqD9yOm4s4kCQQC1WwnUP8fX0V/OkK2TUdfJ1rsmSJ1spNRStDDKtsErB4BPvr/q\
O+EmthTPGq9jzfe4hDr9W2tclxNa70oOolS3AkEA7qZDM0BHALxK/2Q6lU2zpjfh1gUxLAlg\
OGyIGTafq1o0y2b5HGrmwVYQAGaUPlBLVRLRBxhL+kXnSzXhTR1xRA==\
";

CryptoPP::StringSource tasdst(privKey_Base64, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(privKey)));

string pubKey, pubKey_Base64 =
"MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQDJuMm4VGrfDMJB8FscBBUP+9MLCSE/mN7C\
FBYcBfAbJbCa4ZE2GG4TGDPYB4v0+WNJu+YeI13rGTYH79ElIntf+mlnutXmRmwjFIFof+vq\
JzbUDoiVfPFYMQSRuOTjop5Rt5ezSaWWbpIhFzapb+HY9pli4LenCAvBs9kEIXG/cwIBEQ==\
";

CryptoPP::StringSource tasdst2(pubKey_Base64, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(pubKey)));

RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
char const *a = privKey.c_str();
size_t dataLen = privKey.size();
privateKey.Load(CryptoPP::StringStore((const byte*)a,(size_t)dataLen).Ref());

RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
char const *b = pubKey.c_str();
dataLen = pubKey.size();
publicKey.Load(CryptoPP::StringStore((const byte*)b,(size_t)dataLen).Ref());

string message = "RSA Signature", signature;
std::cout << message << std::endl;

RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer signer(privateKey);

StringSource ss1(message, true,
    new SignerFilter(rng, signer,
        new StringSink(signature)
    )
);

string encoded, decoded;

CryptoPP::StringSource(signature, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(encoded)));

CryptoPP::StringSource tasdst3(encoded, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(decoded)));

RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Verifier verifier(publicKey);
StringSource ss2(message+decoded, true,
    new SignatureVerificationFilter(
        verifier, NULL,
        SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION
    )
);
```

Comment: After just a little looking around I found out that there is problem with building libcryptopp and just a few lines of code fixed symptoms that was before.

Here is what to change in GNUmakefile:
https://sites.google.com/site/ievgensychov/cryptopp

Comment: do you still have a question? Its not clear from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

After just a little looking around. I found out that there is problem with building libcryptopp and just a few lines of code fixed symptoms that was before.

Here is what to change in GNUmakefile:
https://sites.google.com/site/ievgensychov/cryptopp

Yes, problem is solved.